# Tabber widget overlapping other content on sidebar in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, widget

I've implemented the following tabbed widget in the sidebar of my blog (Blogger hosted): http://mylpgb.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-add-5-tabbed-widget-for-blogger.html

It works just fine in Chrome and Firefox (the submit box is a bit wonky in Firefox, but whatever), but in Internet Explorer, I've got some problems. When the content under a tabber tab gets a little long, it overlaps the other gadgets on my sidebar. Actually, it looks like the rest of the gadgets/content are properly pushed down, but the image directly below the tabber just gets run over. There's nothing special about that image--it's just a simple image tag.

I tried setting the table height to 100%, but no dice. I'm kind of learning as I go, so I'd be very grateful for any troubleshooting tips. Thank you.

Comment: Have you an example url?  Or a http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I can share my tabber code, if that helps. I just added the tabber in an HTML/Javascript gadget, above the rest of the gadgets on my sidebar. Would that be enough info?